# Configuration data for a custom workflow activity

Tags: dynamics-crm

When deploying plug-ins for MS Dynamics CRM, using the CRM plugin registration tool, you can set secure and unsecure configuration values. You can the setup a constructor to access these values in a plug-in.  Is this or something similar available to custom workflow activities? If so, how is it used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is nothing comparable for workflow activities.

For this purpose, we usually define input parameters for the workflow activies. The configuration is then entered in the workflow designer.